# G is a group and it acts on X

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

If G is a group and it acts on X and it has 6 orbits.H is a subgroup of G, with the property that $[G:H]=3$ (H has only 3 left cosets), how many orbits can it have in X?

By using the orbit-stabilizer theorem: $|G|=|Gx||G_x|$ and so $|H|=\frac{1}{3}|Gx||G_x|$ but I do not know how to use this information..

Comment: First, some intuition could be nice to have. Do you expect $H$ to have more or fewer orbits than $G$, for instance? Could it possibly have equally many orbits?

Comment: @Arthur I was thinking that H is smaller than G so maybe it has fewer orbits, but I do not see the connection to the left cosets

Comment: The orbit $Gx$ of a fixed element $x\in X$ is all possible $gx$ with $g\in G$. If $H$ is a subset of $G$, the set of possible $hx$ for $h\in H$ is smaller. So each orbit is smaller, meaning there are more of them. How about whether it's possible to have equally many? Can you think of an example?

Comment: Oh ok, smaller orbits but a larger number of them. To have equally many, maybe only when G=H @Arthur

Comment: We can't have $G = H$, since $[G:H] = 3$.

Comment: So it may not be possible @Arthur

Comment: It is possible, you just need to be a bit more careful in the construction. For instance, what about $G = H\times \Bbb Z_3$, where the $\Bbb Z_3$ part of $G$ doesn't really do anything to $X$? Then $H$ contains all the actual actions that $G$ does on $X$, and must therefore have the same orbits.

Comment: @Arthur Makes sense. However I still do not understand how to solve the problem

Comment: Each $G$-orbit splits into $1$, $2$ or $3$ $H$-orbits, so the answer could be any number $k$ with $6 \le k \le 18$. For all such $k$ there is a corresponding example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but an example that might point you in the right direction.

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $X=\left\{re^{\frac{ k 2\pi i}{6}}\mid r,k\in \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}\right\}$. Let $\overline{1}$ in $G$ act on $X$ by rotation over $60$ degrees with respect to the origin, i.e. $\overline{1}\cdot re^{\frac{k2\pi i}{n}}= re^{\frac{(k+1)2\pi i}{n}}$. It is easy to check that this action has $6$ orbits.

Let $H=\left\{\overline{0},\overline{3}\right\}$, then $H$ is a subgroup of index three. The action restricted to $H$ is determined by the action of $\overline{3}$. Clearly, $\overline{3}$ acts as a flip (rotation over $180$ degrees). Each orbit now has $2$ elements in it, thus there are $18$ orbits. Can you guess a formula from this example?

Comment: I understand  that each orbit has 2 elements, and I guess you multiplied the index by the no. of orbits?

Comment: That would be a reasonable guess, it is not true however. You can easily define $G'=\mathbb{Z}_6\times K$ but keep the same action as above (so $K$ doesn't really do anything). However, the above example provides an upper bound on the number of orbits. Derek Holt's comment gives you an idea on how to show this.